How to calculate ETH Total Supply (PoS)
I'm trying to calculate the total supply of ETH in real time, block by block, starting from a known supply at a specific block, using the native APIs for execution layer and consensus layer.
Here are my assumptions:

The total sum of validator balances in the consensus layer includes: existing 32 ETH for each validator, new ETH created from the issuance policy, ETH burned due to penalties.
Every time a new block is created, in the consensus layer: existing ETH is added by new validators deposits; new ETH comes out due to withdrawals.

Currently, this is the logic I'm following:

Retrieve a block from the execution layer (eth_getBlockByNumber).

From the block, trace back to the parentBeaconBlockRoot and subsequently to the block's slot (/eth/v1/beacon/headers?parentBeaconBlockRoot=${parentBeaconBlockRoot}).

For that slot, retrieve the list of all existing validators (/eth/v1/beacon/states/${slot}/validator_balances).

Sum up the balances of all validators and subtract 32 ETH for each validator with a balance > 0, in order to exclude the existing ETH from the new validators born in that block.

Repeat the previous steps for the next block.

Calculate the difference between the results of the second block and the first block.

Retrieve the total withdrawals that occurred in that specific block and add them to the result to account for the ETH withdrawn from the consensus layer between blocks.

Subtract the fees burned for that block.

Add the result to the known supply.

Continue with a new block starting from step 5.


However, the total supply I obtain using this method is much higher than what is displayed on various platforms like Etherscan, CoinMarketCap, etc.
Please let me know if you find any inconsistencies in my logic or have interesting points to discuss together. Thank you.
